# Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream while reading InputStream into a file

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm trying to put an InputStream into a file and getting the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'handleMessage' threw exception
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
```

Here is the snippet that is causing it

```
HSLFSlideShow ppt = new HSLFSlideShow(fs)
ObjectData[] embeddes = ppt.getEmbeddedObjects()
embeddes.eachWithIndex { ObjectData entry, int i ->
  File f = new File (fileToSave)
  f.withOutputStream { w -> 
     w << entry.getData() //This causes the error
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the `ObjectData` class `getData()` method https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/ObjectData.html#getData()

I'm using Apache POI 3.10-FINAL

Comment: Hard to tell anything. Provide a SSCCE if You hope to get some help here.

Comment: does the code work just with the exact file?

Comment: Looks like it might be a corrupt file. If you open the file in PowerPoint, then do Save-As, does the new file work fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream reading a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129419/java-io-eofexception-unexpected-end-of-zlib-input-stream-reading-a-file)