# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream reading a file

Tags: java, zlib

I wrote the following code to read Freebase data dumps and I got error **java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream** and I do not know how should I solve this problem. 
Could you please tell me where is the problem.

```
 GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.freebaseTriples));

 String line;
 Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(in);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(decoder);
 ParseFreebaseRDF rdfs= new ParseFreebaseRDF();

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     rdfs.parser(line);
 }

 br.close();
 decoder.close();
 in.close();
```

Comment: Use a try-catch block

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl you mean the while condition has some problems? by the way If I user try catch then I only capture the exception not solve it.Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in this code, whatever its merits or demerits may be. The problem is in the *file.* It is truncated: possibly not downloaded correctly, for example.

Comment: this error is not happening for all files. This is occurring for one file while downloading and reading 4 files at the same time using multi threading. it's fine to catch exception & move forward or something else can be tried?